# I don't understand the typeclass constraints in the list subtraction

Tags: haskell, typeclass

This is a list subtraction example.

```
(\\) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[] \\ _  = []
xs \\ [] = xs
(x:xs) \\ (y:ys)
  | x == y    = xs \\ ys
  | otherwise = (x : (xs \\ [y])) \\ ys
```

Firstly, I don't know what Eq represent.

Secondly, should `a` be `[a]` instead in the typeclass constraints? Because the input must be lists.

Comment: "Firstly, I don't know what Eq represent." — In order to remove elements from a list, the compiler has to be able to tell whether two elements are the same.  How would it do that if they don't belong to `Eq`?

Comment: Ok, so typeclass constraints could have more than one condition.

Comment: Oh, no. `Eq a` should be together as one condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Eq` is the type class containing `==`. So the constraint `Eq a` says that `a` must be a type that can be compared using `==`.

It's `Eq a` and not `Eq [a]` because we want to be able to compare elements of the lists, not the lists themselves (though if we did, we could still do that because `Eq a` implies `Eq [a]`).